# disable automatic color correction and white balance in DaVinci Resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve, color-correction

Please tell me how I can disable automatic color correction and white balance in DaVinci Resolve? I'm editing a video recorded on my iPhone. I imported it, cropped it, but the colors changed when it was exported.
I opened my project, made a right click on the timeline and selected Reset Node Grade, but after I reexported the video the colors remained unchanged.

My Deliver settings are default:

Video Format: QuickTime

Codec: H.264

Encoding Proflie: Auto

Entropy Mode: Auto

Advanced Settings:

Color Space Tag: Same as Project

Gamma Tag: Same as Project

This is what I have in my original video and what I want to get

[image]

This is what I get after exporting the video

[image]